# jquery loading screen before html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement this [codepen](http://codepen.io/msisto/pen/LntJe) into an html page. The idea is that it fades away after everything on the page loads. This is what I currently have.

HTML

```
<div class="js">
<body>
<div id="preloader"></div>
<!-- WEBSITE -->
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

(*** ALERT: You cannot try to close a div tag after having closed the body element ***)
CSS

Lots of CSS so I put it on [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjwEmx)

---

JQUERY

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


  $(window).load(function() {
    $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });

});
```

So it seems to be working fine except I can't seem to figure out the purple background. The spinner works perfectly but if I put `background: #774CFF;` in the `.js div#preloader` it doesn't cover the entire page in purple, only within the spinner.

Comment: the .js div should be moved inside of body

Comment: you don't need the `$(window).load` when inside a `.ready()` callback

Comment: Your HTML in the question is invalid.

Comment: It works fine I just need to edit to make purple full screen,

Answer (score 0):

You assign the `background-color` on the `#preloader`, which has 30px width and height.
So, either you apply the `background-color` to the `body`

```
body{
  background-color:#774CFF;
}
```

either you wrap the `#preloader` with another element and stretch it to fit the screen:

HTML

```
<div id="preloader-wrapper">
  <div id="preloader">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#preloader-wrapper{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-color:#774CFF;
}
```